# Blank screen after explosion in Call of Duty: Black Ops

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I've collected the radio and tag 3 items, but when I'm asked to help push open an entrance there is then a explosion and then my screen goes dark/black.

I have been stuck here forever. Has anyone come across this before? What can I do to get past it?

I'm from Vietnam, if it helps.

Comment: Vietnam in Minecraft maybe? :P

Comment: What platform are you playing the game on?

Comment: Hi Andy, welcome to Arqade! I've tried to make your question clearer, but we could use some more info. As TZHX says - are you playing on a console? Xbox/PS3? or are you playing on a computer? Also: What is the name of the mission you are getting stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have a bugged disc.

I believe I understand the scene you are describing. Just as you and Woods are head to head with a tank, Woods asks for your assistance on opening the door before you get f#*!ed up.

As you hit the door the tank explodes a vehicle over you. The screen should not go black, you simply become disorientated and have to continue to push through with Woods. Pretty sure some guy dies on top of you as well... Covers you in brains and stuff.

Borrow a friends disc, or attempt to install yours to the hard drive.

Hope this helps!